# How to activate an event by clicking a specific paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("p").click(function(){
     alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
 });
});
```

It works, but I wanted to restrict it to a specific paragraph, example:

```
<p class="titleM" id="tituloExist">ENTER WITH A NEW ACCOUNT</p>
```

Comment: See jQuery's [Class Selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and [ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Comment: Change the selector to select by the id: `$("#tituloExist")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may choose which you want by id or class

```js
// by Class
$("p.titleM").click(function(){
   alert("By Class");
});

// by ID
$("p#tituloExist").click(function(){
   alert("By ID");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="titleM" id="tituloExist">ENTER WITH A NEW ACCOUNT</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `id` of the paragraph in the selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("p#tituloExist").click(function(){
     alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="titleM" id="tituloExist">ENTER WITH A NEW ACCOUNT</p>
```